# Unable to add button for redirection

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-dom

I have been using a React.js template to get started to learning it. On the **index.js** it is redirecting to my admin dashboard panel. I want to add a signin signup page before it gets redirected, if I do so all my routes and imports needs to be changed hence I am trying to add the code on the same page.

**Here is my index.js code:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./assets/css/animate.min.css";
import "./assets/sass/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react.scss?v=1.3.0";
import "./assets/css/demo.css";
import "./assets/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css";

import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.jsx";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/admin" render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
       // I WANT TO ADD BUTTON HERE SUCH THAT WHEN I CLICK ON THE BUTTON THEN IT GETS 
       REDIRECTED TO THE DASHBOARD
       <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/dashboard" /> 
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I want to add a button, such that when I click on the button only then it gets redirected to the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You are using  component to render at path= "/admin" .. what you want to achieve can be done by adding a button in AdminLayout where you click on it and then use

```
onClick(e) => {this.props.history.push("/admin/dashboard")}
```

if you want the button to go from when you are at path ="/" then render something on that path like a component that will have a button that takes you to admin/dashboard.

```
<Route path="/" render={props => <button onClick= {props.history.push("/admin/dashboard")}>Click me </button>} />
```